# How to receive a notification when a view will appear?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

When I'm doing a half-page curl modal transition:

[image]

How can I tell when the page has been restored back to it's current state?  I want to call something when the "settings" view has been closed.

I tried to use `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` but it doesn't seem to get called when closing the view.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register an NSNotificationCenter observer on your master view and post the notification on your background view. And instead of viewWillAppear you can use viewDidLoad.

// EDIT: sample code to get a touch gesture in a given rect

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([[event allTouches]count] == 1) {
        UITouch *t = [[touches allObjects]lastObject];
        CGPoint p = [t locationInView:self.view];
        if (p.y < 200) NSLog(@"above 200");
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of using a notification, but the problem is that if the user taps the top of the page curl it goes down all by itself without my control.

Comment: make a NSLog() in touchesBegan:withEvent: and look if it get called / and maybe you can put the notification in dealloc

Comment: How can I detect if a touch is above a certain point on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

In your viewDidLoad, register a Notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(updateView:) 
                                             name:@"updateRootView"
                                           object:nil];
```

Now this is the notification that we call

```
- (void) updateView:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    /*  notification received after the page is uncurled  */
}
```

The calling method:

```
- (void) unCurlPage
{
    // All instances of TestClass will be notified
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateRootView" object:self];
}
```

And don't forget to dealloc the notification

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I know how to do a notification, but the problem is I can't call it because if the user taps the page curl I don't have any control over what happens as it's system managed.

Comment: you my friend. Are a f-ing life saver.

Answer (score 0):

ViewWilAppear is a UIViewController message/method. If you are only changing views, it won't get called. What does the code you are using to close the settings view look like?

---

### Edit

It sounds like you need to refactor a bit. Assuming all this is handled by the parent UIViewController for this settings view, you could implement something like:

```
- (void)settingsPanelOpen {
    // present the modal
    // hook to inform of opening (if necessary)
}

- (void)settingsPanelClose {
    // dismiss modal
    // hook to inform of closing
}
```

Then settingsPanelClose could have a hook into it if you need to know when the settings closes.

The other thing you could do is subclass UIViewController as SettingsViewController and override the **viewDidDisappear:** method to kick off a SettingsDidSave notification or otherwise inform your app that it has closed.

Comment: Well, with this type of transition there's two ways to close it.  1. A button.  I'm using `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` to dismiss it.  However, if the user taps the page curl it also returns to the previous view.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem is that I don't have control over the dismissing if the user taps the page curl.  That's why I wanted to see if it's possible to know when the view appears.

Comment: Why not? How does the dismissal with the curl differ? Regardless, "The other thing you could do" should handle that.